# Ajax & WordPress on Front End - Database not updating

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I'm working on a WordPress website. I'm having a bit of a difficult time getting the user input to update the database.

JS:

```
var ID = $(this).attr('id');
var name = $("#name_input_"+ID).val();
var createDate = $("#created_input_"+ID).val();
var stats = $("#status_input_"+ID).val();
var dateExpire = $("#disbanded_input_"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&name=' + name + 
'&createDate=' + createDate + '&stats=' + stats + '&dateExpire=' + dateExpire;

// can place loading image here

if (name.length > 0 || createDate.length > 0 || 
stats.length > 0 || dateExpire.length > 0) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../edit-items.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      alert(err.Message);
    },
    success: function (html) {
      $("#name_"+ID).html(name);
      $("#createDate_"+ID).html(createDate);
      $("#stats_"+ID).html(stats);
      $("#dateExpire_"+ID).html(dateExpire);
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Enter text to make an edit.");
}
});
```

PHP (edit-items.php)

```
global $wpdb;

if($_POST['id']) {
    $id = esc_sql($_POST['id']);
    $name = esc_sql($_POST['name']);
    $created = esc_sql($_POST['createDate']);
    $stats = esc_sql($_POST['stats']);
    $dateExpire = esc_sql($_POST['dateExpire']);

    $query = "UPDATE items SET itemName='$name', createDate='$created', itemStats='$stats', dateExpire='$dateExpire' WHERE committee_id='$id';"

    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query));
  }
```

Whenever I try to update the table, I am able to do it successfully on the front end, but on refresh, the data change does not stick. Checking the database further verifies that the data has not been changed... It seems like the "success" is passing in the AJAX, but for some reason, it's not updating the database.

Any insight on this would be helpful!

**Edit**
Decided to start using the `admin-ajax.php` method. Everything is the same except I changed the url in the JS to `url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",` and the code from `edit-items.php` is now in `functions.php` like so:

```
 function editCommittee() {  
  global $wpdb;

if($_POST['id']) {
    $id = esc_sql($_POST['id']);
    $name = esc_sql($_POST['name']);
    $created = esc_sql($_POST['createDate']);
    $stats = esc_sql($_POST['stats']);
    $dateExpire = esc_sql($_POST['dateExpire']);

    $wpdb->update('itemsTable',
                array(
                    'name' => $name
                ),
                array(
                    'committee_id' => $id
                ),

                array(
                  '%s'
                )
  );
  echo $id;
  exit();
  }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_editItems', 'editItems');
```

Comment: You are passing a string format,you cant access $_post['id'], instead of that pass json as Tomsaz suggested and add another key in json ,action: 'editCommittee' and echo 'success'; and die; at the end of php function editCommittee @sleepy_daze

Comment: I've set the following: `data: dataString,` `dataType: 'json',` `action: 'editCommittee'` in my JS file. Also added `or die();` at the end of `editCommittee()` function. I've found that if I remove the query from `functions.php`, I don't get the 500 Internal Server Error. Maybe there's something wrong with my query?

Comment: Try to echo query and run in mysql, one mistake i see is you are committee id as string in where @sleepy_daze

Comment: Thanks for that catch, @parthmahida! I've gotten a little further, please check out my code edit above. No more 500 Internal Errors, and I am able to see the HTTP response headers. It seems like data is passing through `admin-ajax.php` well. However, whenever I edit the data on the frontend, it comes through successfully as a `GET` request instead of a `POST`... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so first localize your `ajaxurl` object

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frontend_enqueued_scripts' );

/**
 * Localization object
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function frontend_enqueued_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'script', 'ajax_object', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ));
}
```

If you have, in your `functions.php` a place where you are enqueuing front end scripts place the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` part in there. Also if you are placing your ajax calling javascript inside a file that is not called `custom.js` change the name to point to it. I always use `custom.js` as a file where I store all my theme related javascript.

The above code will create an `ajax_object` object on your front end that will be available to the code inside the `custom.js`, since you've attached it to that script. The handles in the enqueued file and localized script (in our case `script`) must be the same for this to work.

Then you can create, in `functions.php` file, or in any included file where you put your ajax functions, a callback function

```
/**
 * Front and back end ajax hooks.
 */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_edit_committee', 'edit_committee' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_edit_committee', 'edit_committee' );

/**
 * Ajax callback function
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function edit_committee() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_POST['id'], $_POST['committee_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['committee_nonce'] ), 'committee_nonce_action' ) && '' !== $_POST['id'] ) { // Input var okay.
        $id          = ( isset( $_POST['id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['id'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['id'] ) ); : ''; // Input var okay.
        $name        = ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && '' !== $_POST['name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['name'] ) ); : ''; // Input var okay.
        $created     = ( isset( $_POST['create_date'] ) && '' !== $_POST['create_date'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['create_date'] ) ); : ''; // Input var okay.
        $stats       = ( isset( $_POST['stats'] ) && '' !== $_POST['stats'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['stats'] ) ); : ''; // Input var okay.
        $date_expire = ( isset( $_POST['date_expire'] ) && '' !== $_POST['date_expire'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['date_expire'] ) ); : ''; // Input var okay.

        $updated = $wpdb->update( 'itemsTable', array(  'name' => $name ), array( 'committee_id' => $id ), array( '%s' ) );
        if( false !== $updated ) {
            wp_die( 'success' );
        } else {
            wp_die( 'fail' );
        }

    }
}
```

I added the sanitization checks. It's crucial that you include a nonce in your form that you'll use to submit the data.

You can add it by placing

```
wp_nonce_field( 'committee_nonce_action', 'committee_nonce' );
```

inside the `<form>` element on your front end. This will generate a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces), which is a good security measure, especially when you're writing to the database.

The callback function will check if the nonce is set, if the `$_POST['id']` variable is set and not empty, and will first verify the nonce.

Then you can carry on with the execution of the function.

I left all the `$POST` variables there even though you're not using them, but maybe you'll want to use them later on. I also sanitized them and unslashed them.

The `// Input var okay.` comment is for phpcs purposes, you can ignore that.

Then you preform the update. If you have the `itemsTable` in the database it should update it with the data you provided.

The last but not the least is the javascript code. I assumed that you are preforming the ajax call on some kind of button click. This needs to be changed for it to work (I used `#update_button`, you'll place the correct id or class of your button)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#update_button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var ID = $(this).attr('id'); // Button that is clicked is in $(this) object
        var name = $('#name_input_'+ID).val();
        var create_date = $('#created_input_'+ID).val();
        var stats = $('#status_input_'+ID).val();
        var date_expire = $('#disbanded_input_'+ID).val();

        // Can place loading image here
        if ( name.length > 0 || create_date.length > 0 || stats.length > 0 || date_expire.length > 0 ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action' : 'edit_committee',
                    'id' : ID,
                    'name' : name,
                    'create_date' : create_date,
                    'stats' : stats,
                    'date_expire' : date_expire,
                    'committee_nonce' : $( '#committee_nonce' ).val()
                },
                cache: false,
                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log( jqXHR + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown );
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    if ( html == 'success' ) {
                        $('#name_'+ID).html(name);
                        $('#createDate_'+ID).html(create_date);
                        $('#stats_'+ID).html(stats);
                        $('#dateExpire_'+ID).html(date_expire);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Enter text to make an edit.');
        }

    });

});
```

I've also changed variable names to `short_name` format, instead of `shortName`. I find that neater.

Notice that for the url, we used `ajax_object.ajaxurl` - this is the localized `ajax_object` from the beginning, referencing to the correct path of the `admin-ajax.php` file. The data is just your string, but written as an object.

So when you click the button, your ajax call will put all your data in a global `$_POST` variable.

You can check it by having inspector running and clicking Network > XHR tab

[image]

Also if you're not sure what your `$_POST` variable holds, put

```
error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
```

in your `edit_committee()` function, right before the validation check (the if condition). If you have debugging enabled in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
```

You'll have `error_log.txt` in the root of your WordPress installation, and you can check what the contents of the `$_POST` variable is.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: No problem, happy to help ;)

Comment: would you by any chance have any ideas about how to implement something similar but for an insert statement?

Comment: Everything would be the same, except in the ajax callback function you'd use `$wpdb->prepare` with insert method. I'm sure there is something about that in the codex for wpdb.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Here is the issue, for ajax requests we use `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.
Also your data string should cantain `&action=editItems` ( same as you use in `wp_ajax_editItems` )

You ajax request code should look like...

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: dataString + '&action=editItems',
    cache: false,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      alert(err.Message);
    },
    success: function (html) {
      $("#name_"+ID).html(name);
      $("#createDate_"+ID).html(createDate);
      $("#stats_"+ID).html(stats);
      $("#dateExpire_"+ID).html(dateExpire);
    }
  });
```

For more details check out https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Just never call the `admin-ajax.php` directly. You should localize it first, and then reference to it through an object.

Comment: Yeah @dingo_d, It's recommended to **not** use hard coded URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that you didn't send POST data to PHP file - check it. Type `var_dump($_POST)` in php, and add `console.log(html)` in success part of ajax.

Try also change your `dataString` variable in JS to this:

```
var dataString = {
 id:ID,
 name:name,
 createDate:createDate,
 stats:stats,
 dateExpire:dateExpire
};
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like anything is being printed to the console. However, I am getting this error:
`jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST http://url.com/~directory/committee_edit_ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Interestingly, whenever I set the AJAX url to `"../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` it prints 0s to the console whenever the input updates on the front-end (still not updating to the database though)

Comment: If you want to use admin-ajax.php check example form documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: Any thoughts on the POST 500 Internal Server Error? I will likely go to the admin-ajax.php method if this doesn't work. I honestly wasn't sure if that method was restricted to using Ajax only on the Admin Dashboard side...

Comment: Check php error log to find out why it gives internal server error. Did you load wp core in `edit-items.php`?

Comment: No, `edit-items.php` only consists of the PHP in my original post. Will check PHP error log when I get home

Comment: Oh, so you have to include `wp-load.php`. Without it `global $wpdb` is NULL

Comment: Still no dice... PHP error log isn't displaying anything, but I'm still getting the 500 internal server error. Hmm...

Comment: Please provide 500 server error details from the log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->update( 'table',
array( 'column' => $name),
array( 'ID' => 1 ),
array( '%s'), 
array( '%d' )
);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why your posted code will be answer this question.