# How to use AJAX form submit in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have custom page template with a form with 2 dropdown and 1 input submit. When the user submit the form, the result will be displayed, this is working properly. But I have a problem, the browser is reload when fetching the data in the database.

I want to use AJAX to prevent reloading of page. I saw some article about Ajax WordPress, but I cannot work it correctly.

Anyone can please help me out? How to do with AJAX? How can I call the custom PHP file in the AJAX?

AJAX (functions.php)

```
    function ajax_enqueue_sl(){
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_load_sl', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/alternate-dropdown.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ajax_load_sl', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajax_enqueue_sl);

add_action('init', 'registerFormAction');
function registerFormAction(){
    // To handle the form data we will have to register ajax action. 
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
}

function submitAjaxForm_callback(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_page(9208)){
        //ROCK ON!
        if (isset($_POST['store_list']) && $_POST['store_list'] != 'Select by Store'){
        $store_list = $_POST['store_list'];
        $stores= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT street FROM tablename WHERE stores= '" . $store_list . "' AND col IN ('test') ORDER BY street ASC", OBJECT));
        foreach ($stores as $record_s){
            echo '<div class="records">';
            echo '<div><span class="icons-tabbed-store icon-icon-stores">' . $record_s->street . '</span></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } elseif (isset($_POST['mall_list']) && $_POST['mall_list'] != 'Select by Mall'){
        $mall_list = $_POST['mall_list'];
        $street = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT stores FROM tablename WHERE street= '" . $street_list . "' AND col IN ('test') ORDER BY stores ASC", OBJECT));
        foreach ($street as $record_m){
            echo '<div class="records">';
            echo '<div><span class="icons-tabbed-store icon-icon-stores">' . $record_m->stores . '</span></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

PHP w/ HTML (test.php)

```
$results_street = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT street FROM tablename WHERE code IN ("test1") ORDER BY street ASC', OBJECT);
$results_stores = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT stores FROM tablename WHERE code IN ("test2") ORDER BY stores ASC', OBJECT);

<form action='' method='post' name='myform' id="myform">
<div class="pos-div">
<select name="street_list" id="filterbystreet">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by">Select by</option>
    <?php
    foreach($results_street as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['street_list']) && $_POST['street_list'] == $option->street)
            echo '<option name="street_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->street .'">'. $option->street .'</option>';
        else    
         echo '<option name="street_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->street .'">'. $option->street .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<span class="or">or</span>
<div class="pos-div">
<select name="store_list" id="filterby">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by">Select by</option>
    <?php 
    foreach($results_stores as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['store_list']) && $_POST['store_list'] == $option->stores)
            echo '<option name="store_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->stores .'">'. $option->stores .'</option>';
        else    
         echo '<option name="store_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->stores .'">'. $option->stores .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="List all partner stores" class="pos-submit"/>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['store_list']) && $_POST['store_list'] != 'Select by Store'){
        $store_list = $_POST['store_list'];
        $stores= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT street FROM tablename WHERE stores= '" . $store_list . "' AND code IN ('test3') ORDER BY street ASC", OBJECT));
        foreach ($stores as $record_s){
            echo '<div class="records">';
            echo '<div><span>' . $record_s->street. '</span></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } elseif (isset($_POST['street_list']) && $_POST['street_list'] != 'Select by'){
    $street_list = $_POST['street_list'];
    $streets = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT street FROM tablename WHERE street_list= '" . $street_list. "' AND code IN ('test3') ORDER BY stores ASC", OBJECT));
    foreach ($streets as $record_m){
        echo '<div class="records">';
        echo '<div><span>' . $record_m->stores . '</span></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

ajax_js.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //$('#myform').submit(ajaxFormSubmit);

    $('#filterbystreet').change(function(){
        $('#filterbystore').prop('selectedIndex','Select by Store');
    });

    $('#filterbystore').change(function(){
        $('#filterbystreet').prop('selectedIndex','Select by');
    });

    jQuery('.pos-submit').on('click',function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var myform = jQuery('#myform').serialize(); 

        jQuery.ajax({ 
            type:"POST", 
            // Get the admin ajax url which we have passed through wp_localize_script(). 
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url, 
            action: "submitAjaxForm", 
            data: myform, 
            success:function(data){ 
                jQuery(".records").html(data); 
                console.log(data);
            } 
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I noticed that you're using jQuery, are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: @Ronald, yes jquery library is already included

Comment: Please use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40649208/629127) as a reference how to use ajax calls. The `admin-ajax.php` shouldn't be called this way, and you should `preventDefault()` on click or select event...

Comment: @dingo_d, pls see my updated pos with updated js and ajax function. the results are not displayed even in the console.log

Comment: Do you see the ajax call in the console (look at the Network tab, at XHR requests)?

Comment: yes, i saw the admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 1):

Do not submit the form on ajax call. You can use like this.

```
    jQuery('#filterbymall').change(function(){

        jQuery('#filterbystore').prop('selectedIndex','Select by Store');
        ajaxSubmit();        

    });

    jQuery('#filterbystore').change(function(){

        jQuery('#filterbystreet').prop('selectedIndex','Select by');        
        ajaxSubmit();      

    });


function ajaxSubmit(){
    var myform= jQuery("'#myform").serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: myform,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery(".records").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

and change this

```
  <input type="submit" value="List all partner stores" class="pos-submit"/>
```

to

```
  <input type="button" value="List all partner stores" class="pos-submit"/>
```

input type submit to button

Comment: i tried your js, but it's not working. I called the AJAX properly in `functions.php`?

Comment: check the script is include or not by view the page source

Comment: i double checked it, and it's included @vel

Comment: jQuery(document).on("change","#filterbymall",function(){
   jQuery('#filterbystore').prop('selectedIndex','Select by Store');
   ajaxSubmit();        

  });

  jQuery(document).on("change","#filterbystore",function(){
   jQuery('#filterbystreet').prop('selectedIndex','Select by');        
   ajaxSubmit();     
  });
try this

Comment: jQuery(document).on("change","#filterbymall",function(){ jQuery('#filterbystore').prop('selectedIndex','Select by Store'); ajaxSubmit(); }); jQuery(document).on("change","#filterbystore",function(){ jQuery('#filterbystreet').prop('selectedIndex','Select by'); ajaxSubmit(); });

Comment: use like  this 
jQuery(document).on("change","#filterbymall",function(){

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129212/discussion-between-user014019-and-vel).

Comment: where you define this function Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxSubmit is not defined

Comment: in the js file.

Comment: you wrote the function ajaxSubmit  somewhere else within document ready function. define this function out side document ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below :

- Change the input type submit to div. (so that page doesn't gets
  refreshed when form is submitted).
- Provide some ID to button/div.
- Write onlcick jquery for that ID, as below : (explained below #2)
- Now "select_options" will be the name of your ajax hook example :
- Create the definition for the call back function "my_action_callback" (explained #3)
- function my_action_callback(){ echo 'testing';}, then "testing" will
  the result in the output string of jQuery function.

## 2 :

```
$('#ID_OF_DIV').click(function(){
    var admin_ajax_url = $('#admin_ajax_url').val();
    $.post(
          admin_ajax_url, 
          {
              'action': 'select_options',
              'name1':   value1,
              'name2':   value2,
              .... so on,
          }, 
          function(output){
          //output will be the response from the ajax code code.
          });
});
```

## 3

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_select_options', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_select_options', 'my_action_callback' );
```