# AJAX form submit in WordPress not working correctly (conti...)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is a continuation of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836700/how-to-use-ajax-form-submit-in-wordpress). I have custom page template with a form with 2 dropdown and 1 input submit. When the user submit the form, the result will be displayed, this is working properly. But I have a problem, the browser is reload when fetching the data in the database.

I'm trying to use AJAX to prevent refreshing browser. I just updated the AJAX function in `functions.php` and JS. The page is not refreshing now when the user click the submit button. But the results are not displayed. I'm using `is_page`, to displayed different result in the specific pages

How to fix this? How can I call the custom PHP file in the AJAX?

AJAX (functions.php)

```
function ajax_enqueue_sl(){
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_load_sl', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/alternate-dropdown.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ajax_load_sl', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajax_enqueue_sl);

add_action('init', 'registerFormAction');
function registerFormAction(){
    // To handle the form data we will have to register ajax action. 
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_submitAjaxForm','submitAjaxForm_callback');
}

function submitAjaxForm_callback(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_page(9208)){
        //ROCK ON!
        if (isset($_POST['store_list']) && $_POST['store_list'] != 'Select by Store'){
        $store_list = $_POST['store_list'];
        $stores= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT street FROM tablename WHERE stores= '" . $store_list . "' AND col IN ('test') ORDER BY street ASC", OBJECT));
        foreach ($stores as $record_s){
            echo '<div class="records">';
            echo '<div><span class="icons-tabbed-store icon-icon-stores">' . $record_s->street . '</span></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } elseif (isset($_POST['mall_list']) && $_POST['mall_list'] != 'Select by Mall'){
        $mall_list = $_POST['mall_list'];
        $street = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT stores FROM tablename WHERE street= '" . $street_list . "' AND col IN ('test') ORDER BY stores ASC", OBJECT));
        foreach ($street as $record_m){
            echo '<div class="records">';
            echo '<div><span class="icons-tabbed-store icon-icon-stores">' . $record_m->stores . '</span></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

PHP w/ HTML (test.php)

```
$results_street = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT street FROM tablename WHERE code IN ("test1") ORDER BY street ASC', OBJECT);
$results_stores = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT stores FROM tablename WHERE code IN ("test2") ORDER BY stores ASC', OBJECT);

<form action='' method='post' name='myform' id="myform">
<div class="pos-div">
<select name="street_list" id="filterbystreet">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by">Select by</option>
    <?php
    foreach($results_street as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['street_list']) && $_POST['street_list'] == $option->street)
            echo '<option name="street_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->street .'">'. $option->street .'</option>';
        else    
         echo '<option name="street_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->street .'">'. $option->street .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<span class="or">or</span>
<div class="pos-div">
<select name="store_list" id="filterby">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by">Select by</option>
    <?php 
    foreach($results_stores as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['store_list']) && $_POST['store_list'] == $option->stores)
            echo '<option name="store_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->stores .'">'. $option->stores .'</option>';
        else    
         echo '<option name="store_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->stores .'">'. $option->stores .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="List all partner stores" class="pos-submit"/>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['store_list']) && $_POST['store_list'] != 'Select by Store'){
        $store_list = $_POST['store_list'];
        $stores= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT street FROM tablename WHERE stores= '" . $store_list . "' AND code IN ('test3') ORDER BY street ASC", OBJECT));
        foreach ($stores as $record_s){
            echo '<div class="records">';
            echo '<div><span>' . $record_s->street. '</span></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } elseif (isset($_POST['street_list']) && $_POST['street_list'] != 'Select by'){
    $street_list = $_POST['street_list'];
    $streets = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT street FROM tablename WHERE street_list= '" . $street_list. "' AND code IN ('test3') ORDER BY stores ASC", OBJECT));
    foreach ($streets as $record_m){
        echo '<div class="records">';
        echo '<div><span>' . $record_m->stores . '</span></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

ajax_js.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //$('#myform').submit(ajaxFormSubmit);

    $('#filterbystreet').change(function(){
        $('#filterbystore').prop('selectedIndex','Select by Store');
    });

    $('#filterbystore').change(function(){
        $('#filterbystreet').prop('selectedIndex','Select by');
    });

    jQuery('.pos-submit').on('click',function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var myform = jQuery('#myform').serialize(); 

        jQuery.ajax({ 
            type:"POST", 
            // Get the admin ajax url which we have passed through wp_localize_script(). 
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url, 
            action: "submitAjaxForm", 
            data: myform, 
            success:function(data){ 
                jQuery(".records").html(data); 
                console.log(data);
            } 
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First at all `wp_enqueue_scripts` function and  `wp_localize_script`, you should register then enqueue the handle in the function, as the example in the codex

```
  // Register the script
  wp_register_script( 'ajax_load_sl', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/alternate-dropdown.js', array('jquery'));

  wp_localize_script('ajax_load_sl', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'))););

  // Enqueued script with localized data.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_load_sl');
```

Details and example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

In your php script, you didn't mentioned if it stands in a function (I think so, and assuming this), at the top of the function, you need to add

```
global $wpdb;
```

Then you could use `$wpdb`

tablename, will never be recognize, your need to put `wp_posts` where `wp_` is your table prefix, or `$wpdb->prefix.'posts'` if you don't want to matter about the prefix.

```
global $wpdb;

$results_street = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT street FROM wp_posts WHERE code IN ("test1") ORDER BY street ASC', OBJECT);
$results_stores = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT stores FROM wp_posts WHERE code IN ("test2") ORDER BY stores ASC', OBJECT);
```

Change wp_posts with you right db name.

Tell me if it works after!

Comment: i already did that. please take a look to my post. but still the results are not displayed

Comment: You really leave tablename !!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `function ajax_enqueue_sl(){
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_load_sl', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/alternate-dropdown.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ajax_load_sl', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajax_enqueue_sl);`

Comment: I already have that inside `submitAjaxForm_callback` function

Comment: I forgot a word enqueue js and sql

Comment: i already enqueue my js. it's already in code (see in the question)

Comment: Sorry but for me, your way can't work, after wp localize, you must enqueue the handle, there's an order and a method to do it. Don't you see that you need to enqueue the handle after not before ?