# Why can't I seem to get Ajax to communicate with my PHP $wpdb delete file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

thank you for taking a look at my question which goes as follows:

I'm trying to delete a record in an MYSQL database when I click a link which in HTML looks like this:

```
<li><a class="msg-action-delete" href="#" data-msgid="<?php echo $mesage_posts->msg_id; ?>">delete</a></li>
```

I don't want the page to reload after clicking the button so I use Ajax:

```
$('.msg-action-delete').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var wp_directory = directory_uri.stylesheet_directory_uri;

  var msg_id = $(this).attr('data-msgid');

  $.ajax({
    url : wp_directory+'/modules/messaging/delete-messaging.php',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    type : 'POST',
    data: {
         'msg-id' : msg_id
     },
     success: function(data) {

         console.log(data);
         console.log(msg_id);
         alert('ajax worked');

     }

  });

});
```

I'm using WordPress as a CMS which has a class $wpdb that helps out with interactions to the db, for the delete scripts is in a file called elete-messaging.php :

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$msgid = $_POST['msg-id'];
echo $msgid;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpeddit_msg';

$wpdb->delete($table_name, array('msg_id' => $msgid));

$wpdb->show_errors();
```

When I click the delete link it does nothing, no errors in console.

I would appreciate any help I can get on this, **thanks!**

Comment: Maybe it time to include some wp-file where `$wpdb` get defined?

Comment: Can you check to which URL in network section the request is going ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax & WordPress on Front End - Database not updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473066/ajax-wordpress-on-front-end-database-not-updating)